# Same results displayed while using Kaminari and Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-masonry

I'm using Kaminari, Masonry and the add-on to Infinite Scroll. I got the infinite scrolling with masonry but every time I go on the page and see the list of items it renders the same items over again at least 25 times, giving me 650 listed items when there's only 26. My code is below and the question I ask is why is this happening?

> items_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @items = Item.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
  end
```

> index.html.erb

```
<div id='items-ctnr' class='row'>
  <div class='infinite-scroll page clearfix'>
    <%= render @items %>
  </div>
</div>

<nav id="page-nav">
  <%= paginate @items %>
</nav>
```

> index.js.erb

```
$("#items-ctnr").append("<div class='infinite-scroll page clearfix'><%= escape_javascript(render(@items)) %></div>");
```

> _items.html.erb

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div class='item box'>
    <div class='name'>
      <%= link_to item.name, item %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

> items.js

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#items-ctnr, #user-items-ctnr');

  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 6;
      }
    });
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
    nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more items to load.',
        img: '/assets/masonry/loader.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright the problem was the two `@items` variables rendering over each so I'm guessing it rendered several times between the two until it had an internal error that the log didn't pick up. Probably some rails fallback that I'm unfamiliar with.

Well, this works so far when I removed the variable in the item partial:

> _items.html.erb

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<% end %>
```

and just kept the index code in the same place which was this:

```
 <div class='infinite-scroll page clearfix'>
    <%= render @items %>
 </div>
```

Learned something new about how `render` and `@items` works.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js.erb` I think you also need to update `#page-nav` block, because right now you're serving new data with ajax but don't change pagination block.

Something like this:

> index.js.erb:

```
$("#items-ctnr").append("<div class='infinite-scroll page clearfix'><%= escape_javascript(render(@items)) %></div>");
$("#page-nav").replaceWith("<nav id='page-nav'><%= escape_javascript(paginate(@items)) %></nav>");
```

Comment: Thx but no luck with this one.